# In React, animate a centered element upon expand

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using React, and I centered an element horizontally and vertically using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`, with appropriate centering css.

Inside of it I have some content, when I add content to that element with javascript, the whole element recenters properly, but elements jump from their initial place to their next place.

I'd like to animate it in place, is that possible?

Going from this:

```
<div table>
  <div table-cell>
    <div>First Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div table>
  <div table-cell>
    <div>First Content</div>
    <div>Second Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(didn't include css to make it easy to read)

Comment: can you show this behaviour somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this by adding the new elements with a special class like:

```
<div table>
  <div table-cell>
    <div>First Content</div>
    <div class="slide-in">Second Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make the special class have `max-height: 0`. After it has been inserted into the DOM replace the maximum height with some large enough pixel value to fit the contents on screen. Make sure you have a transition on `max-height`.

```
.slide-in {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}
```